# Android activity adds 2mb every time

Tags: java, android, memory-management, android-activity, android-memory

everytime I quit my Android app and restart, it consumes 2 Mb extra, for example if I restart my app 3 times, it consumes 6 Mb more. I use the back button to quit and I clean all references in OnDestroy().

I went through all the posts in stack overflow pertaining to memory management and memory leak in Android, I also did a MAT but there is no way my activities are leaking memory(holding reference),

I also tried the same thing with other applications but they maintain a constant memory usage of +/- 0.75 Mb.

I am confused about Android memory management.

Comment: Android does not naturally "quit" apps, although this can be done by going to App settings and pressing "Force stop" button. Is this your scenario? Or maybe you are speaking about pressing Home button to pause your activity and go to the home screen, then pres the app icon again?

Comment: I quit the app by pressing back button, I remove all the references on destroy.

Comment: code is here 
http://pastebin.com/TaqGBAMw

Comment: I think you're leaking a `Handler` because you create a new one every time you go into `onCreate`.

Comment: for current activity, any time you press back or home button, activity will call `onStop()` to hide or end it. In case of yours, memory leak is the most suspicious cause. How do you confirm "no way my activities are leaking memory"?

Comment: 2MB sounds like a graphics resource leak. What does your SplashScreen activity look like?

Comment: I set the Handler to null ondestroy, still the same

Comment: these are the two actvities which are displayed before i click back button, If memory leak is happening it should be in these 2 activities only!

1st activity http://pastebin.com/TaqGBAMw
2nd activity http://pastebin.com/YYHijCBB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this Fixed! The problem was, in my Grid View Adapter I was setting the typeface for the grid icon texts everytime, I should have set the typeface in the On Create generically.